# Having trouble fetching the other side of a many-to-many MYSQL relationship via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many

EDIT:  DevlshOne solved the duplication issue, but I'm still getting the weird array result.

I apologize if this question has been asked and answered. I used the site search, Google, and watched a few YouTube videos, but I didn't find anything that was basic enough for me to apply it to my context.

Essentially I have three tables: tool, metal, and tool_contains_metal, the latter being the many to many table, of course. (I know these are weird examples, but I'm trying to build a simple project to learn the database ropes)

```
|----tool ----|
id | name | use
```

.

```
|- tool_contains_metal -|
   tool_id | metal_id
```

.

```
|-- metal -- |
   id | name
```

I want to use PHP to query the database and return the metals contained in any given tool.

I have a tool class and a metal class, of course, and my strategy so far has been to make a function in the metal class which queries the database, and returns the result.

This is this query I have at the moment, cobbled together after reading various help files.

```
SELECT metal.id, metal.name FROM metal
            INNER JOIN tool_contains_metal tool_contains ON metal.id = tool_contains.metal_id
            INNER JOIN tool ON tool_contains.tool_id =1
```

With 1 being hard-coded in, for the moment, because I know the tool with the id of one should be associated with two different metals.

<strike>When I run that query on PHPMyadmin, it returns the two rows...but it repeats them 12 times, for a total of 24 results. I assume I'm just off on the syntax somewhere.</strike> **Thanks DevlshOne!** But I'll include my function, for the sake of completeness. 
.

```
public static function find_metals_in_tool($toolId){
    global $database;
    $sql = "SELECT metal.id, metal.name FROM metal
            INNER JOIN tool_contains_metal tool_contains ON metal.id = tool_contains.metal_id
            INNER JOIN tool ON tool_contains.tool_id =1";

    $result_set = $database->query($sql);
    $result_array = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set);
    return $result_array;
}
```

when I print_r($result_array), it displays one line: 
    Array ( [0] => 1 [id] => 1 [1] => Steel [name] => Steel )
Which doesn't seem to be what I want. At the very least there should be two results for this particular tool. Another oddity is when I run echo count($result_array) it displays 4.

Anyway, hopefully this wasn't overly wordy, but I figured more information was better than too little.

I really appreciate any tips/pointers anyone can give me.

Comment: use `GROUP BY metal.id` to eliminate the 12x duplications

Comment: Awesome! That solves the duplication on PHPMyadmin, but it doesn't change the result I get when I call the function. It still gives me: Array ( [0] => 1 [id] => 1 [1] => Steel [name] => Steel )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to iterate through the results try this:

```
$result_set = $database->query($sql);
$return = array();
while($result_array = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set)){
    $return[] = $result_array;
}
return $return;
```

Ref:

```
Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows in resultset.
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php